# Angular: Component scss styles not applied to tags supplied to [innerHTML] of div?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I've got a MatDialog which is supplied with an HTML string by its parent when it's constructed.  The HTML string is the source of a named div's content, and contains `<table>` tags embedded within the html, but for some reason the table style defined in the dialog's scss file isn't applied to the string I specify as `[innerHTML]` , although it works fine for `<table>` tags hard-coded directly into the html file.

Is there some way I can get the dialog to render the innerHTML with styles contained in the styles template for the dialog componenet?

```js
    export class DialogAgreementViewer implements AfterViewInit {
      constructor(public dialogRef:
        MatDialogRef<DialogAgreementViewer>, @Inject
        (MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: string, protected _sanitizer : DomSanitizer){
          this.agreementText = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
        }
      public agreementText : SafeHtml;
      @ViewChild('agreementText') agreementTextCtl : ElementRef;
    }
```

HTML:

```html
    <p>Agreement Template</p>
    <table>.          <-- Defined table styles are applied to this table.
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Title</td><td>Name of Work</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <div [innerHTML]='agreementText'></div> <-- Table styles not applied here.
```

SCSS:

```
    table, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
       
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 75%
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should disable encapsulation for that component. You can do it like this:

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Import ViewEncapsulation along with Component:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

and set encapsulation for the component in the decorator, along with selector, template, css styles etc:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-app',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // <---------
})
```